# Nagios ignores parents

Tags: nagios

I've set up a Nagios Server to poll my company's servers. The monitoring works nice but on the network map I got a flat layout with question marks. I've added the parent directive to some hosts but nagios seems not not care when drawing the map or the tooltip. I get validation errors when I add typos to the config so I'm sure the config file is read.

Here is my config:

```
define host {
    use                generic-host
    host_name          storage-control
    address            [ip-address]
    icon_image         database.gif
    statusmap_image    database.gd2
    hostgroups         storages
}

define host {
    use                generic-host
    host_name          storage-sp1
    address            [ip-address]
    icon_image         database.gif
    statusmap_image    database.gd2
    hostgroups         storages
    parents            storage-control
}

define host {
    use                generic-host
    host_name          storage-sp2
    address            [ip-address]
    hostgroups         storages
    parents            storage-control
}
```

Did I miss something?

Cheers,
AC

Comment: hmm just like my kids, damn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The only thing I had to do was to stop nagios, delete the objects.cache file specified in the object_cache_file directive in the nagios.cfg file and start it again.